# WooCommerce Hook before "New Order"-Mail is sent

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

During my WooCommerce order, the user selects an image that gets uploaded to the server. Now I need to edit this image (resize, trim etc. with ImageMagick) BEFORE the "new Order" emails are sent, because I attach this image to these emails.

I tried the payment_complete hook, but this one is too late, the mails are already sent. I also thought about doing it in the mail templates, but it only needs to be done once, so it has to especially be before the mails are sent out.

Of course it should happen on the server after the "thank you" page, the user shouldn't have to wait for this processing.

Edit: The hook should deliver the order id because I need to access the order items.

Where can I insert/hook my code to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Well the new order emails are triggered to run on the `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification` and `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification` hooks, with default (10) priority.

Therefore, you should be able to run your code on the same hooks with a lower priority (say, 5).

Failing that, you could skip the notification and just focus on the order status change, so the following hooks:

`woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing` and `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With your hooks, it actually works to run some code before the emails are sent, the problem still is that the page waits for it to complete. What I want is that there is the "thank you"-screen where the order is finished to run my code so the user does't have to wait, but it looks like the emails are sent before this page is reached, right?

Comment: That's true you will have to wait until the function completes. To avoid this you could process the image asynchronously after it is uploaded.

Comment: Yeah right, but that would give me the problem of not being sure if the async task is done at the moment to user completes the new order. Looks like the way to go would be to start an async task on the thank you page which processes the image and afterwards triggers the emails..