# WooCommerce doesn't show custom fee in email sent to the customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have built a plugin which adds a fee to an order from WooCommerce. I add this fee to the order with the wc_add_order_item method with order_item_type 'fee'. The problem i'm having is that the fee doesn't show up in the email that is sent to the customer when that customer placed an order. If i understand it correctly WooCommerce is normally adding al the fees and shipping costs in `<tfoot>` from email-order-details.php with $order->get_order_item_totals(); and loops trough them.

The weird thing is that while i tried to look for a solution i came across the 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification' [hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30653178), this hook (if again i understand correctly) triggers right before the email is sent to the user. In the callback of this hook you will have an order ID at your disposal and i called this hook in my functions.php from my theme. In the callback i searched for the correct order and used this to check what was in $order->get_order_item_totals(). I expected there was only the basic stuff and my added fee wouldn't show up, except it did.

How is it possible that while my fee is visible in $order->get_order_item_totals() before the email is sent to the customer but WooCommerce won't loop trough it in email-order-details.php? Or am i missing something? Any thoughts?

The ultimate goal is to have my custom fee in the email sent to the customer.

For reference this is the loop in email-order-details.php:

```
$totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

if ( $totals ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
        $i++;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which code you have used to add the fee to your order, But I have added a service fee to my woocommerce order, and it also shows in the woocommerce email notifications.

Try adding this code to your functions.php or make a plugin out of it. You can edit the fee amount according to your needs. Here is the code

```
/**
 * Add a standard $ value service fee to all transactions in cart / checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_add_svc_fee' ); 
function wc_add_svc_fee() { 
global $woocommerce; 

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
return;


// change the $fee to set the Service Fee to a value to suit
$fee = 1.00;


    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Service Fee', $fee, true, 'standard' );  

}
```

If you want the fee or surchage to be a percentage of the order total, use the following code

```
/**
 * Add a 1% surcharge to your cart / checkout
 * change the $percentage to set the surcharge to a value to suit
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 0.01;
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

Using any of the above code the Fee or Surcharge will appear in the email notifications.

Comment: Shahid, Thank you for this.  I want to show this surcharge fee (custom duty) only when select one particular shipping method. Do you know how to display your code when selecting a shipping method with AJAX i guess ?
Thx !

Comment: Do you know how to display a custom fee as a column in order table?